# Delete dot from all new lines only if its first character

Tags: text-processing

I want to remove dot character from all new lines only if they start with them.

```
example:
test.example.com
123.example.com
999.example.com
.asd.example.com
.1.1.example.com

would become:
test.example.com
123.example.com
999.example.com
asd.example.com
1.1.example.com
```

is there a simple way to do this in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "in bash" - it's simple to do in `sed`, or similar regex-based text editors:

```
$ sed 's/^[.]//' example
test.example.com
123.example.com
999.example.com
asd.example.com
1.1.example.com
```

The brackets around the period prevent it from having its bare regex interpretation (which would delete any single leading character) - you could also use a backslash escape `s/^\.//` to make it literal `.`

Answer (score 0):

Let the file in which your data resides be **input.txt**

You use use the following command to replace text using regular expressions. visit (**$ man sed**) for more info

```
$ sed 's/^\.//' input.txt
```

This will print the result in terminal output.

If you want you can redirect output to a file using

```
$ sed 's/^\.//' input.txt > output.txt
```